# How to prevent gatsby layout re-render when navigating between routes?

Tags: gatsby, particles.js

Gatsby re-renders the particlesjs canvas when navigating between pages. Is there any way I can prevent that?

Heres a codesandbox showing what's happening https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-rgb-07hk1

Answer (score 8):

Figured out the answer to my own question:

Gatsby docs describe how to prevent a Layout component from unmounting [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/layout-components/#how-to-prevent-layout-components-from-unmounting)

According to [this page](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-layout/), Gatsby v1 would not unmount the Layout component but now in v2 it does and you also have to import the Layout component on each page that you need it.

You can reimplement v1 behavior with [wrapPageElement](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#wrapPageElement) or by using [gatsby-plugin-layout](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-layout/) which implements it for you